# RX buffer events for several seconds after first event is triggered

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've got a filewatcher from which I observe the created and changed events.
I want that when the first event is triggered (created or changed) it need to start buffering for 10 seconds and after those 10 seconds I want to proces the buffered events.

What I've got already is this:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(FileSystemWatcher, "Created")
                .Merge(Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(FileSystemWatcher, "Changed"))
                .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                .Subscribe(list =>
                {
                   Debug.WriteLine("Do something");
                });
```

This code does 'Debug.WriteLine("Do something");' every 10 seconds.

Edit:
Ok let me try to explain it with a time line.

1. File watcher is idle, no events are triggered.
2. After a unknown period of time a file is placed in the directory
3. The created event is triggered
4. The observable list starts buffering (all the events) for 10 seconds
5. After those 10 seconds the subscribe action gets executed and it will process all events at once

Hopefully this will make something clear

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Why don't you consume `list`? Or do you want to handle each item in the list individually?

Comment: Do you only want it to trigger once or something? It sounds like your solution is appropriate.

Comment: On a sidenote: you should keep a reference the subscription and dispose it when you are no longer interested in the events. If you do not dispose the subscription and it goes out of scope then it might still keep a strong reference to the event (and potentially causes leaks).

Comment: Edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the following behavior:

1. After an initial event, buffer all events for the next 10 seconds.
2. Once that 10 second window closes, the next should trigger a new 10 second buffer for all events 10 seconds after that.

So let's say we have 5 events evenly spread out in 5 seconds, a 13 second gap, then another 5 events evenly spread out in 5 seconds. Marble diagram would look like this:

```
timeline: 0--1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27
events  : x--x--x--x--x-------------------------------------x--x--x--x--x------------------
stdbuff : |----------------------------|-----------------------------|---------------------
desired : BeginCapture-----------------Return---------------BeginCapture------------------Return
```

The problem with using straight-forward `Buffer` is that it would look like the `stdbuff` notated above, and break up the second group of events into two groups, resulting in two lists for the second group of events: one with three events, one with two events. You want one list (for that second group), using a logic like the `desired` stream. Start capturing at 0, return list at 10. Start capturing at 17, return list at 27.

If I'm misunderstanding you (again), the please post a marble diagram, similar to the above, representing how you want things to work.

---

Assuming I understand you correctly, the below code will work...

```
//var initialSource = Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(fileWatcher, nameof(FileSystemWatcher.Created))
//  .Merge(Observable.FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventArgs>(fileWatcher, nameof(FileSystemWatcher.Changed)));

    //Comment this out, and use the above lines for your code. This just makes testing the Rx components much easier.
var initialSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(5)
    .Concat(Observable.Empty<long>().Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(13)))
    .Concat(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(5));

initialSource
    .Publish( _source => _source 
        .Buffer(_source
            .Scan(DateTimeOffset.MinValue, (lastPrimary, _) => DateTimeOffset.Now - lastPrimary > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) ? DateTimeOffset.Now : lastPrimary)
            .DistinctUntilChanged()
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        )
    )
    .Subscribe(list =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Time-stamp: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"List Count: {list.Count}");
    });
```

**Explanation**:

First we need to identify 'primary events', those that represent the `BeginCapture` annotations in the `desired` stream depiction above. That can be found like this:

```
 var primaryEvents = initialSource
        .Scan(DateTimeOffset.MinValue, (lastPrimary, _) => DateTimeOffset.Now - lastPrimary > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) ? DateTimeOffset.Now : lastPrimary)
        .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

Once we have the `BeginCapture` events, which can represent a window opening, it's pretty easy to find the `Return` events, or the window closing:

```
 var closeEvents = primaryEvents.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

In practice, since nothing happens between a close and an open that we care about, we really only need to worry about the close events, so we can shrink it to this:

```
 var closeEvents = initialSource
        .Scan(DateTimeOffset.MinValue, (lastPrimary, _) => DateTimeOffset.Now - lastPrimary > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) ? DateTimeOffset.Now : lastPrimary)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Plug that into `Buffer` with the `closeEvents` being the `bufferBoundaries`:

```
var bufferredLists = initialSource
    .Buffer(initialsource
        .Scan(DateTimeOffset.MinValue, (lastPrimary, _) => DateTimeOffset.Now - lastPrimary > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) ? DateTimeOffset.Now : lastPrimary)
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    );
```

Finally, since we have multiple subscriptions to `initialSource`, we'll want to use `Publish` to ensure concurrency works properly, leading to the final answer.

Comment: Please write up a timeline for how you expect it to work.

Comment: This is working indeed. I thought there would be a simpler solution. It's kinda hard to read what is happening here and that's not really improving the maintenance for this project. I'm not the only one working on it you see.

Comment: Is there a particular part that's confusing? It is four lines, even if they're a bit dense.

Comment: I must admit it's hard to understand at first glance if you don't know well the `Publish`, `Buffer` and `Scan` operators and their overloads. @Shlomo can you explain further why the `Publish` operator is needed here and why their is no need to call the `Connect()` method?

Comment: @AlbertHoekstra if it looks too complicated just put it in a custom observable extension (e.g. `Observable.TriggeredBuffer(TimeSpan bufferDelay)` and document it well. That will make your code maintainable.

Comment: @SimonCorcos, I've been getting that question a lot, so I wrote it up as a Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747350/why-how-should-i-use-publish-without-connect/53747351#53747351