# Why/How should I use Publish without Connect?

Tags: system.reactive, rx.net

Why/how should I use `.Publish()` without a `Connect` or `RefCount` call following? What does it do? Example code:

```
var source = new Subject<int>();

var pairs = source.Publish(_source => _source
    .Skip(1)
    .Zip(_source, (newer, older) => (older, newer))
);

pairs.Subscribe(p => Console.WriteLine(p));

source.OnNext(1);
source.OnNext(2);
source.OnNext(3);
source.OnNext(4);
```

How is `pairs` different from `pairs2` here:

```
var pairs2 = source
    .Skip(1)
    .Zip(source, (newer, older) => (older, newer));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Publish<TSource, TResult>(Func<IObservable<TSource, IObservable<TResult>> selector)` overload is poorly documented. Lee Campbell doesn't cover it in [introtorx.com](http://introtorx.com). It doesn't return an `IConnectableObservable`, which is what most people associate with `Publish`, and therefore doesn't require or support a `Connect` or `RefCount` call.

This form of `Publish` is basically a form of defensive coding, against possible side-effects in a source observable. It subscribes once to the source, then can safely 'multicast' all messages via the passed in parameter. If you look at the question code, there's only once mention of `source`, and two mentions of `_source`. `_source` here is the safely multicasted observable, `source` is the unsafe one.

In the above example, the source is a simple `Subject`, so it's not really unsafe, and therefore `Publish` has no effect. However, if you were to replace `source` with this:

```
var source = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Print me once");
    o.OnNext(1);
    o.OnNext(2);
    o.OnNext(3);
    o.OnNext(4);
    return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;
});
```

...you would find "Print me once" printed once with `pairs` (correct), and twice with `pairs2`. This effect has similar implications where your observable wraps things like DB queries, web requests, network calls, file reads, and other side-effecting code that you want to happen only once and not multiple times.

**TL;DR:** If you have an observable query that references an observable twice, it is best to wrap that observable in a `Publish` call.

Comment: Uuurrrgh. I was about to upvote but I then saw the `return System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable.Empty;`. That's kind of like running with scissors - it's dangerous and, if you're just using it for illustration then you should have a big disclaimer with it. I do love your answers on Rx in general.

Comment: Thanks. I don't share your allergy to that particular anti-pattern. It's not great, but simple `Create` examples pretty much require it. I wrote this because I was repeatedly explaining it in other questions. Perhaps write up a Q & A why you hate `Create` + `Disposable.Empty`.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Can you please let me know where to write up a Q & A? I assume you don't mean as a question here? Also, please give me some examples of where `.Create` requires `Disposable.Empty`?

Comment: That's what I meant. Write up a question, and tick the checkbox to add an answer. That's what I did here.

Comment: As for `.Create` without `Disposable.Empty`... cases like this one where you want a side-effect (for whatever reason) at subscription, then a regular old observable with no side-effect at termination.

Comment: But doing `Observable.Create<int>(o => { Console.WriteLine("Print me once"); return Observable.Range(1, 4).Subscribe(o); });` avoids the `Disposable.Empty`. Can you think of an example where you can't avoid it?